# Can I remove X-Forwarded-* headers from NodeJS https requests?

Tags: node.js, https, x-forwarded-for

I have a NodeJS script I'm using to collect some web data, but the website I'm pulling from seems to have a strict no-proxy policy. Their API outright denies any requests with the `X-Forwarded-For` header set. I confirmed this behavior using Python requests, any value (even a single IP or blank string) gets rejected.

It seems by default the `https` module adds this header, along with `'X-Real-Ip': 'xx.xx.xx.xx'`, and `'Connection': 'close'`. Is there any way to disable this, so I can make a request without the `X-Forwarded-For` header?

I can't provide a fully reproducible example without sharing API access, but the following is how my request is being made (pulled from a basic tutorial):

```
const https = require('https');
const options = {
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/foo/bar',
    method: 'GET'
}
const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})
req.end()
```

...and I get the following `request.headers` from my Django webserver:

```
{
    'Host': 'example.com',
    'X-Real-Ip': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    'X-Forwarded-For': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    'Connection': 'close'
}
```

Is this behavior something I can adjust? I saw some explainations on how to remove this header from ajax calls, or higher level packages such as http-proxy, but nothing for the base https package.

Pardon any bonehead oversights, I normally work in Python for this type of script but there are other dependencies which necessitate NodeJS for this project.

Comment: `X-Forwarded-For` comes from an intervening proxy server between your client and server.  It's considered useful information for the server so that it can know what was the original IP address of the client because the IP address at the other end of the connection to the server will be the proxy server, not the client.  There's no downside to receiving this header.  Perhaps you could change the proxy configuration to disable this header, but it is generally considered to be useful information for the server to have access to so I don't see what would be gained by disabling it.

Comment: I agree with the usefulness, with the tables reversed I have even used it personally to track user activity on our internal corporate site, but for whatever reason it is completely rejected by this site I’m pulling from. I can try opening a support ticket to understand why, but I’d rather just disable it if possible.

Comment: nodejs `https` (and `http`) **does not add X- headers** -- only `Connection:close` (there's no API to send a second request), and (1.1-required) `Host:whatever` . In fact it **can't** do Forwarded-for and Real-IP because in many environments (i.e. NAT) it doesn't know what your 'originating' address will be. As @jfriend00 said your request is going through a proxy somewhere, which is adding them, and that's what you need to change. Try looking at the cert chain you get to see if it hints at what/where this proxy is, and/or `[tcp]traceroute`.

Comment: Well, it is not your client adding those headers.  They come from some intervening infrastructure (like a proxy).  If all you control is the client, then you cannot do anything about it.  If you control the intervening proxy, then that's where you have to fix it.  Or fix the server to not mind that they are present.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this header was not being added by `https`.

Using `traceroute` as suggested by dave_thompson_085, I was able to find an up-stream content filter all our corporate traffic goes through. My personal computer was on a different subnet, which is why the request worked fine when I tested with Python, but the server I used for the NodeJS call was behind this content filter.

We added an exclusion to the content filter to prevent our server from routing through it, and the X-Forwarded-* headers went away. Hopefully this helps someone else with a similar misunderstanding.